# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, function, indexing, attributeerror

I've made function which finds the list including specific word by input value.
I'd like to calling 'index' from 'search' function. But I've got Attribute error message like this ;

```
  if distance.haversine([search.index]['geometry']['coordinates'][1],
 [search.index]['geometry']['coordinates'][0],t_dicc['tuits']['coordinates']['latitud'],
 t_dicc['tuits']['coordinates']['longitud']<=radius):
 **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'index'**
```

I've tried to modify many times but it didn't work.

```
import os
import string
import json
from pprint import pprint
import distance

def main():

f = open('monumentos-reducido.json', 'r')
mo_dicc = json.load(f)

g = open('tuits.json', 'r')
t_dicc = json.load(g)

def search():

    word = raw_input("monument name : ")

    if(word in value for word in ('nombre')):
        try:
            StopIteration

            if word > 1:

                index = next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(mo_dicc['features']) if d["properties"]["nombre"] == word)

            pprint(mo_dicc['features'][index])

        except StopIteration:

            exit()


search()


radius = input("radius(meters) : ")


def search2rad(search):

    resultlst = []

    if distance.haversine([search.index]['geometry']['coordinates'][1],[search.index]['geometry']['coordinates'][0], t_dicc['tuits']['coordinates']['latitud'], t_dicc['tuits']['coordinates']['longitud']<=radius):
        index = next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(t_dicc['tuits']) if d['coordenadas'])
        resultlst.append(t_dicc['tuits'][index])
    print resultlst

search2rad(search)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making call to `search2rad` function as `search2rad(search)` where `search` is the function. Within `search2rad()`, you are doing:

```
if distance.haversine([search.index]['geometry']['coordinates'][1],[search.index]['geometry']['coordinates'][0], t_dicc['tuits']['coordinates']['latitud'], t_dicc['tuits']['coordinates']['longitud']<=radius):
```

Here you have mentioned `search.index`. It is raising error since it is function (with no attribute as `index`).

I think what you want to do is to pass the value returned by `search()` call to `search2rad()`. For that, you may do:

```
 search2rad(search())
```

But the cleaner way will be to do it like:

```
 index = search()
 search2rad(index)
```

Comment: @Justin Editted the answer. I think that is what you require

Comment: Thank you, but I can't print search2rad(index), how can I print? I'm sorry.

Comment: **NameError: global name 'index' is not defined** Error occurs like this

Comment: I will suggest to take this code to your teacher as there are many simple bugs related to coding, and it is hard to explain each concept over here. For example `try: StopIteration` in `search()`. That is definitely not what you need. Also, your `search()` should `return index`

Comment: Ok, I see, Thank you for helping me.